# How to generate a histogram so that it has exactly n bins between a set range in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, distribution

I have a vector of data that can takes values between 1 and 100. When I plot a histogram with a bin size of 10, I would expect 10 bins with ranges of 1-10, 11-20, etc. Yet, I end up getting a plot that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the ranges of the outer bins go beyond the bounds for the values that my data can take (0 and 100).

**Is there a way I can generate the histogram so that it has exactly n bins between a set range?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything you want with the `breaks` argument to `geom_histogram`. You can set specific (and arbitrary) binwidths if that pleases you. The `breaks` argument overrides the `bins` and `binwidth` arguments.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
x <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE))
ggplot(x) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x), breaks = c(0, 13, 27, 45, 88, 100), color = "black") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 13, 27, 45, 88, 100))
```

[image: histogram with arbitrary breaks]

If you want n equal bins in a specific range (say 0-100), use `breaks = seq(0, 100, 100/n)`. This can be useful if you want to have a range that is wider than the data. For example, in my random sample, no value greater than 91 is present, but I know that 100 is a possible value, so my bin needs to extend to 100.

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for the answer! I clarified my question because I realized I wasn't effectively communicating what I am trying to do

Comment: @Nova - I updated my answer to generate what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a binned scale with geom_bar

```
ggplot(data.frame(v=sample(1:100, 100, TRUE)), aes(x=v)) + 
geom_bar() +
scale_x_binned(n.breaks = 10)
```

example https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvx7r.png

Comment: Hi Ricardo, this is more along the lines of what I would like. Is there a way to do this with geom_histogram?

Comment: R help for geom_histogram says that "In addition to geom_histogram, you can create a histogram plot by using scale_x_binned() with geom_bar(). This method by default plots tick marks in between each bar." I suppose combining both was not intended by library design and the results are undefined.